# Express: Why cannot use req.body.value in router.use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to expose my form validation script both to `router.post` and `router.get` in a `router.use`. I getting the data from the input fields with `req.body.value`. This is works in `router.post`, but not in `router.use`. I get the following error message (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`) for this code:

```
router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body.firstname.length === 0 || !req.body.firstname.match(/\D+/igm)) {
    var validateFirstname = false;
  } else {
    var validateFirstname = true;
  };

  if(validateFirstname === true) {
    console.log('SUCCESS: Form validated!');
  } else {
    console.log('ERROR: Form not validated!');
  };
  next();
});
```

Someone can explain to me why is that? There's no way to implement this `if else` statement into `router.use`? Later on this will be a huge help to send html div back to the user when the form validated inside `router.get`.

**UPDATE:**

The problem with my validation that it's checking the forms after the load when they are empty, that's why returning `undefined`. But `req.body` works without problem in `router.use` when populated with data. Is there a way to check the input fields except page load?

Comment: Are you using body parsing middleware such as body-parser before you use this middleware function?

Comment: Yes, not in this router, but in my `app.js`, with `extended: true` and `json()`.

Comment: GET requests don't have a body, only POST, so use `.post` if needed

Comment: @dandavis I tried to use `req.value` but it's not working. How to get the data from the form input in `router.use`, if it's possible?

Comment: use something like `req.param.variable_name` for GET params

Comment: Before this it was in a `router.post`. The reason why I want to move the form validation into `router.use`, because I want to trigger a div visibility in `res.render` inside `router.get`, when the form successfully sending the message or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As good alternative how can you organize validation I suggest to use [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) module.

**Sample**

```
var util = require('util'),
    express = require('express'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

// this line must be immediately after express.bodyParser()! 
app.use(expressValidator([options])); 

app.post('/:urlparam', function(req, res) {     
  // VALIDATION 
  // checkBody only checks req.body; none of the other req parameters 
  // Similarly checkParams only checks in req.params (URL params) and 
  // checkQuery only checks req.query (GET params). 
  req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty().isInt();
  req.checkParams('urlparam', 'Invalid urlparam').isAlpha();
  req.checkQuery('getparam', 'Invalid getparam').isInt();
  ...
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
req.param(name [, defaultValue])

    Deprecated. Use either req.params, req.body or req.query, as applicable.
```

This is what you want, already marked deprecated. If you validate by it, makesure use req.param everywhere, avoid bypass the validate.

Comment: Thank You! `req.params` replacing this?

Comment: No. req.params, req.body, req.query are existence independently, please read the doc for more detail. A variable name may be exists in req.params and req.body and req.query at the same time, req.param() just retrive it by the specified order, if you access it directly in req.params or req.body or req.query, it will bypass your validator.